# Flexible centered SVG rotation

Tags: html, css, svg

I was trying to drop unsupported animateTransform:

```
<animateTransform
  attributeType="xml"
  attributeName="transform"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 20 20"
  to="360 20 20"
  dur="1.2s"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
```

in favor of css:

```
const LoadingIconCssRotationStyled = styled(LoadingIconCssRotation)`
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-height: 250px;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;

  @keyframes rotate {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
`;
```

But for some reason my svg started to ratate not inside itself (blue border), but ok. Real problem is that rotating not really around center and do this strange browser window resize. How can i fix this?

[image]

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-ellis-qnol6)

Comment: You need to be a lot more clear with what _"my svg started to rotate not inside itself"_ means.

Comment: @LGSon blue border of svg started to rotate. Real problem is that rotating not really around center and do this strange browser window resize.

Comment: add `transform-box:fill-box`

Comment: @TemaniAfif no changes.

Comment: What doesn't support animateTransform?

Comment: @RobertLongson edge and i heard that google will drop it in future too.

Comment: No, they suspended their deprecation indefinitely due to the outcry they received. Edge is becoming Chrome and in any case you can polyfill Edge via [fakesmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/faq.html)

Comment: @RobertLongson as i read thank to your post, it's just a slow deprecation, so i rather try css: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM%5B126-150%5D

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the second rotation seems imperfect is center of div is not the center of the circle.

Make sure both svg centered the div and the circle is at the center of the svg.

Comment: It has justtify-content: center wrapper, so it should be inside center and if first example works fine, that svg circle is centered too..